# Eclipse Juno doesn't save passwords (SVN & RSE)

Tags: eclipse, svn, ubuntu

I just installed **Eclipse Juno** with following packages:

- Subclipse 1.8.14
- Subversion Client Adapter 1.8.3
- SVNKit Library 1.7.5
- SVNKit Client Adapter 1.7.5
- Remote System Explorer User Actions 1.1.400
- Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime 3.4.0

I can configure and access to remote repositories and ssh connections without problems. But every time I close the Eclipse and run it back, when I try to connect to remote machine or remote repository always ask me for the password even though I select to save it.

This didn't happened with previous versions of Eclipse (Indigo or Helios). Has anyone had the same problem and was able to fix it?

Comment: Can you add which platform you're on, and which JRE you're using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and java-6-sun-1.6.0.26 (although it happen the same on another machine with Ubuntu 12.04 and OpenJDK 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this [issue](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-290?projectKey=SVNKIT&query=#SVNKIT-290). Solved in the latest SVNKit trunk, but the fix wasn't included in any release yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just upgraded the SVNKit at 1.7.5.v1_r9382 version, but the error persists. I hope that in a future version they can solve the problem.